# How to measure memory footprint of an SDK in an iOS app

Tags: ios, performance, memory, sdk, memory-footprint

I have tried measuring memory footprint using various methods - and each method returns a different value.

First way was looking at the small gauge in Xcode while running the app.
It shows 20.9 MB usage:
[image]

Second way was using this code (It shows 38-39MB usage):

```
vm_size_t usedMemory(void) {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &size);
    return (kerr == KERN_SUCCESS) ? info.resident_size : 0; // size in bytes
}

vm_size_t freeMemory(void) {
    mach_port_t host_port = mach_host_self();
    mach_msg_type_number_t host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    vm_size_t pagesize;
    vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;
    
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);
    (void) host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size);
    return vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
}

void logMemUsage(void) {
    // compute memory usage and log if different by >= 100k
    static long prevMemUsage = 0;
    long curMemUsage = usedMemory();
    long memUsageDiff = curMemUsage - prevMemUsage;
    
//    if (memUsageDiff > 100000 || memUsageDiff < -100000) {
        prevMemUsage = curMemUsage;
        NSLog(@"Memory used %7.1f (%+5.0f), free %7.1f kb", curMemUsage/1000.0f, memUsageDiff/1000.0f, freeMemory()/1000.0f);
//    }
}
```

Third way was using instruments which shows approximately 19-20 MB usage

[image]

Bottom line is that I need to understand how to measure the memory footprint of an SDK. (Before adding the SDK and after adding the SDK - or "Blackbox" measurement of the SDK)

How and why are the results so different?

I